# Failed to connect to video room in Twilio using free version

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, screensharing

I'm trying to create a room from android application using twilio sdk = `implementation 'com.twilio:video-android:7.1.2'`
it's throwing an exception that: Unauthorized - you are not authenticated to perform this request,
it was working for 6 months when i developed, but suddenly its throwing this exception.
Is it under maintenance or this api got expired?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a credential error, like maybe with your auth token or API key. Also wondering how you are generating your access tokens

Comment: i'm using functions from consoles and following this link = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lrdYBLEk60&t=169s,

Comment: are you generating a new access token? they're short-lived so they expire

Comment: Yes im generating new access token everytime. but the thing is every user connects with a new room.

Comment: why are they connecting with a new room? is that intentional?

Comment: @lizziepika yes but i fixed that issue

Comment: What was the solution?